# How can we run least squares fitting over implicit variables inside an integral?

Tags: computational-physics, spectroscopy, integration, software, statistics

I am trying to create an algorithm to fit dI/dV data from a superconducting sample. 
For the double integration involved, I ran a loop over a sum function which contains the product of the superconducting DOS and Fermi function.
I defined superconducting DOS separately as a function of broadening function, order parameter (gap) and temperature. 
How, and at what point of the code,  do I introduce a least squares fit that will vary the broadening function and order parameter values to best fit the curve?

Because the curve is a part of the integral whereas the parameters only modify the DOS which is within the integral.

I am working with MATLAB in case this helps.

The equation is:

[image]

The code:

XDOS=abs(real(complex(E,tao)./sqrt(complex(E,tao).^2-delta^2)))
% {XDOS = abs(Re(E - iT/((E-iT)^2 - D^2) where T - broadening and D - energy gap, delta};

for k=1:ndat;
    V=bias(k,1);
    cond(k)=0;

```
for i=1:Nal

    Fermi=-1./(1+exp((E+V+sqrt2*Vmod*sin(al(i)))*qe/(kB*T)));
    % Defining fermi function

    cond(k)=cond(k)+sum(sin(al(i))*wal(i)*(XDOS.*Fermi).*wE);  
    % double integration

end
```

end

- al is the alpha mentioned in the equation
- wal and wE have to do with the limits of integration.
- The data is read out from the input file.

Plotting the array 'cond', and normalising it with experimental curve gives the fitting.
But I would like to run a least squares fitting on tao and delta, which change XDOS. Since XDOS seems to be a numerical value, I can't even plot it to compare it with the experimental data (though dI/dV is supposed to be proportional to superconducting DOS, isn't it?).

(Please Note: I have not designed this code from scratch. Just attempting to incorporate the least squares fitting here)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would [statistics.se] or [scicomp.se] be a better home for this qustion?

Comment: Posting some (pseudo)-code, and the specific equations you are using would be very helpful (and possibly required to answer).

Comment: It might also help if you wrote the equation or expression you're trying to fit data to in the question ( use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) ).